# findstr not able to accept string from multiple FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, findstr

Codes as below:

im getting below error:
FINDSTR: No search strings

I have traced the error an its coming from here:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "!FILENAME!" ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do (...
```

Script is working properly if Im replacing FILENAME variable with exact filename manually. But I need to put it in a loop to execute within multiple files..

```
for /r %%i in (LOG_FILE*.txt) do ( 
    set FILENAME=%%~nxi 

    for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"fin.700 " !FILENAME!') do (
        set /A val1=%%a-3, val2=%%a+3, val3=%%a+4, val4=%%a+11, val5=%%a+13 , val6=%%a+29, val7=%%a+30 
        set "numbers=!numbers!!val1!: !val2!: !val3!: !val4!: !val5!: !val6!: !val7!: "

    )

    set FILENAME=!FILENAME:~0,-1!
    echo !FILENAME!>>tmptmptmp.tmp

    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "!FILENAME!" ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do (
        set linestr=%%b
        echo !linestr!
    )
)
```

Working without the outer FOR loop

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableextensions
rem Assemble the list of line numbers
set numbers=
if exist "tmp" del "tmp"
if exist "tmp2" del "tmp2"
if exist "tmp.txt" del "tmp.txt"

REM for /r %%i in (LOG_FILE*.txt) do ( 
        REM set FILENAME=%%~nxi 
        set FILENAME=LOG_FILE14012015.txt

    for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"fin.700 " !FILENAME!') do (
       set /A val1=%%a-3, val2=%%a+3, val3=%%a+4, val4=%%a+11, val5=%%a+13 , val6=%%a+29, val7=%%a+30 
       set "numbers=!numbers!!val1!: !val2!: !val3!: !val4!: !val5!: !val6!: !val7!: "
    )
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%FILENAME%" ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do (
    set linestr=%%b
    echo !linestr!
    )
```

Comment: I don't see SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Comment: trimmed down the script. I have it on the top part. @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableextensions

Comment: Yes, the error is in the line you said. It must be: `^| findstr /B "!numbers!"`

Comment: somethings wrong with the pipe ^| tried putting usebackq and experiment with quotes, double quotes and accent char. nothing works.

Comment: You do not need to use the `USEBACKQ` option.  Why are you stripping off a single character from the end your filename variable? `set FILENAME=!FILENAME:~0,-1!`

Comment: Im tracing the variable value thats why i got echo command on the next line. Upon checking on the file, string got space at the end. Those commands is for my investigation only.

Comment: I am not seeing anything in your code that would introduce a space into the end of your file name.  You should just be able to use your FOR variable where ever you are using the filename variable.

Comment: I have posted a working version without the outer FOR loop. Maybe someone can help to put an outer FOR loop that will work?

Comment: You still have not use the numbers variable with delayed expansion.  It should not work at all.

Comment: @Squashman: Yes, without the outer loop the second `for` is placed _after_ the first one, so `^| findstr /B "%numbers%"` works correctly in this case. @ Peps: More than an hour ago I said you that you must change previous FINDSTR by this one: `^| findstr /B "!numbers!"`, that is, change the standard `%numbers%` expansion by a `!numbers!` delayed one. Did you tested it? **`:/`**

Comment: This line: `set FILENAME=%%~nxi ` have a space after the "i". To avoid this type of errors, you should enclose in quotes the whole var=value part this way: `set "FILENAME=%%~nxi"`. If you do this, you must remove the `set FILENAME=!FILENAME:~0,-1!` line...

Comment: hi guys. now im trying to revise it to make it cleaner and as you have advised, better to complete this in one piece. I have cleaned and removed `set FILENAME=!FILENAME:~0,-1!` and with `set "FILENAME=%%~nxi"` no more space on the end of the variable. This is my command now and still it doesn't work `for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "!FILENAME!" ^| findstr /B "!numbers!"') do (`

Comment: same error comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I did a workaround as im not able to force the findstr to work properly with my requirements. Did two separate batch script to handle the logic. Below is a copy in case anyone is interested.

bat file that will handle the outer for loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableextensions

::Script that will loop for multiple files and will call search.bat

if exist "tmp.txt" del "tmp.txt"
if exist "multiple_search.log" del "multiple_search.log"
@echo Starting search... >> multiple_search.log

for /r %%i in (LOG_FILE*.txt) do (

    @echo Searching %%i >> multiple_search.log
    call search.bat %%i
                            )

@echo Search completed... >> multiple_search.log

endlocal
```

Main bat file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
setlocal enableextensions

set numbers=
if exist "tmp" del "tmp"
if exist "tmp2" del "tmp2"

    set FILENAME=%1

    for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"fin.700 " !FILENAME!') do (
       set /A val1=%%a-3, val2=%%a+3, val3=%%a+4, val4=%%a+11, val5=%%a+13 , val6=%%a+29, val7=%%a+30 
       set "numbers=!numbers!!val1!: !val2!: !val3!: !val4!: !val5!: !val6!: !val7!: "
    )

    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%FILENAME%" ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do (
    set linestr=%%b
    echo !linestr!
    echo !linestr!>>tmp
    )

    set delim==
    for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (tmp) do (

    echo %%a|find "!delim!" >nul
    if !errorlevel!==0 (echo %%a%%b >> tmp2) else (echo record=%%a%%b >> tmp2)

    )

    set counter=0
    set var=
    for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (tmp2) do (
        set /a counter=!counter!+1
        set var=!var!%%b

        set var=!var: =!
        set var=!var!,

        if !counter! geq 7 (
        echo !var! >> tmp.txt
        set counter=0 
        set var=)
    )

endlocal
```

Comment: It's great to see you came up with a solution to your own problem. But have you seen [Aacini's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405512/findstr-not-able-to-accept-string-from-multiple-for-loop#comment71961324_42405512) and did you try it?  I'm also pretty sure the `%numbers%` instead of `!numbers!` and the space at the end of the assignment of the `FILENAME` variable were the only problems. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Besides that, you should be carreful with the usage of `SetLocal`. Each `SetLocal` sets up a new environment. Therefore each `SetLocal` should normally have an `EndLocal` that closes the environment when it's not needed anymore but in each one of your scripts you have two `setlocal`s at the beginning and only one `endlocal`. You actually don't need 2 `setlocal`s to enable extensions and delayed extension. You can do that with one: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions`. That will also solve the issue of environments not being closed.

Comment: Regardless of your coding errors and not doing anything we suggested you could have kept all the code in one batch file by CALLING to a label instead.